# Calculating Euclidean distance of pairs of 3D points in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, euclidean-distance

I have an Nx3 array that contains N 3D points

```
a1 b1 c1 
a2 b2 c2
.... 
aN bN cN
```

I want to calculate Euclidean distance in a NxN array that measures the Euclidean distance between each pair of 3D points. (`i`,`j`) in result array returns the distance between `(ai,bi,ci)` and `(aj,bj,cj)`. Is it possible to write a code in matlab without loop ?

Comment: look at examples at [tag:bsxfun]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge of your problem is to make a N*N matrix and the result should return in this matrix without using loops.
I overcome this challenge by giving suitable dimension to Bsxfun function.  By default X and ReshapedX should have the same dimensions when we call bsxfun function. But if the size of the matrixes are not equal and one of them has a singleton (equal to 1) dimension, the matrix is virtually replicated along that dimension to match the other matrix. Therefore, it returns N*3*N matrix which provides subtraction of each 3D point from the others.

```
ReshapedX = permute(X,[3,2,1]);
DiffX = bsxfun(@minus,X,ReshapedX);
DistX =sqrt(sum(DiffX.^2,2));
D = squeeze(DistX);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) and [`squareform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html):

```
D = squareform( pdist(X, 'euclidean' ) );
```

---

For beginners, it can be a nice exercise to compute the distance matrix `D` using [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun) (hover to see the solution).

> `elemDiff = bsxfun( @minus, permute(X,[ 1 3 2 ]), permute(X, [ 3 1 2 ]) );`
> `D = sqrt( sum( elemDiff.^2, 3 ) );`

Answer (score 0):

To complete the comment of Divakar:

```
x = rand(10,3);
pdist2(x, x, 'euclidean')
```

Comment: `pdist2` needs approx twice the number of distance computation compared to `pdist` in this case.