# Calculate Euclidean Distance of pairs over 3 points?

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

**MY DATA**

I have a matrix `Median` that contains three qualities, `Speed, Angle & Acceleration`, in virtual 3D space. Each set of qualities belongs to an individual person, termed `Class`.

```
Speed<-c(18,21,25,19)
Angle<-c(90,45,90,120)
Acceleration<-c(4,5,9,4)
Class<-c("Nigel","Paul","Kelly","Steve")

Median = data.frame(Class,Speed,Angle,Acceleration)
mm = as.matrix(Median)
```

In the example above, Nigel's `Speed`, `Angle` and `Acceleration` qualities would be `(18,90,4)`.

**MY PROBLEM**

I wish to know the euclidean distance between each individual person/class. For example, the euclidean distance between Nigel and Paul, Nigel and Kelly etc. I then wish to display the results in a dendrogram, as a result of hierarchical clustering.

**WHAT I HAVE (UNSUCCESSFULLY) ATTEMPTED**

I first used  `hc = hclust(dist(mm))` then `plot(hc)` although this results in a dendrogram of `Speed` only. It seems the function `pdist()` can compute distance between two matrices of observations, but I have three matrices. Is this possible in R? I am new to the language and have found a similar question in MATLAB here [Calculating Euclidean distance of pairs of 3D points in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780633/calculating-euclidean-distance-of-pairs-of-3d-points-in-matlab?rq=1) but how do I write this in R code?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you transform your data.frame into a matrix, all values become characters, I don't think that is what you want... (moreover, you're trying to compute distance with the "class" names as one of the variables...)

The best would be to put your "Class" as row.names and then compute your distances and `hclust` :

```
mm<-Median[,-1]
row.names(mm)<-Median[,1]
```

Then you can compute the euclidean distances between Class with

`dist(mm,method="euclidean")` :

```
> dist(mm,method="euclidean")
          Nigel      Paul     Kelly
Paul  45.110974                    
Kelly  8.602325 45.354162          
Steve 30.016662 75.033326 31.000000
```

Finally, perform your hierarchical classification :

```
hac<-hclust(dist(mm,method="euclidean"))
```

and `plot(hac,hang=-1)` to display the dendrogram.

Comment: Thank you. When I compute the euclidean distances between Class, my matrix shows "0.0000" between Paul and Paul. I note this has is not present in your example. How do I remove the "0.0000" on the diagonal and repeated distances in the top section?

Comment: To answer my own question, I edited your section of code to `dist(mm,method="euclidean"), diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE)` which gave me what I was after.